# How do I remove Computrace from the BIOS

Tags: windows-7

I picked up a computer from my barber and it looks like it's got [Computrace](http://www.absolute.com/en/products/absolute-computrace) installed. Which I'm presuming is the culprit for it randomly bluescreening. Is there any way to remove this garbage from the BIOS without going through computrace? Flash the original bios? Alter the bios code? I just called them and they're of no help since it's a third party purchase.

Where there's a will there's a way, if it can be installed by a consumer, it should be able to be removed by a consumer.

Edit: Very odd thing too. I re-imaged (same way I've done on every computer), and this one doesn't detect the drive as bootable unless I run through PlOp boot manager. Secondary odd thought, I got it rolling with my wim image, and all of a sudden it started bluescreening right at the windows screen, making me think it's the computrace agent.

Comment: I doubt Computrace is causing the blue screens; for an anti theft app its best interests are to stay hidden and unnoticeable... random blue screens aren't what I would call "hidden".

Comment: It's the only thing I can think of given that the image I used works on all other lenovo laptops.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/53698

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Instructions](http://www.ehow.com/how_8388270_remove-computrace-bios.html):

> 1. Turn off your computer by holding in the "Power" button on the computer's tower or the top keyboard bezel if using a laptop.
> 2. Turn the computer back on and wait for the computer manufacturer's logo to appear on the screen. When it appears, press the BIOS access key as seen on the screen immediately to enter into the BIOS menu. BIOS keys vary amongst computer makers, but pressing the "DEL" or "F2" key usually activates the BIOS menu (see Resources).
> 3. Select the "Security" tab on the BIOS main menu using the arrow keys, as you cannot use the computer's mouse. Here you will see three options for Computrace. The "Deactivated" option will more than likely be selected already.
> 4. Select the "Disable" option and press "Enter" on the keyboard to disable Computrace on the computer permanently. You will not be able to reactivate the Computrace module once it is disabled. Press the "Enter" key once more to verify the "Disable" selection.
> 5. Press the "F10" key to save the new BIOS settings and the computer will reboot into the computer's operating system.

After that take a look at [this article](http://www.freakyacres.com/remove_computrace_lojack) to remove the rest.

Comment: It's greyed out in the BIOS.

Comment: In this case you need to re-flash the original BIOS.

Comment: How? I ran the bios utility and it won't flash. It says it's already up to date.

Comment: This does not guarantee that. There is an interesting slides about it https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-Kamlyuk-Kamluk-Computrace-Backdoor-Revisited.pdf

Comment: Once activated, the computrace bios element is designed to be un-disableable with bios reflash or user interaction.  That's the whole point.